# Populate dataset with missing dates (in hour)

Tags: python, dataframe, date, missing-data, populate

I have a dataset that gathers stock option data per hour. Unfortunately some dates and hours are missing due to some maintenance etc..

Here is one exemple with a dataframe (Dates_,Price), as you can see the day "2018-02-08" we only have 2 hours available instead of 24.

[image]

is there a way to find the missing dates ? and also to populate the dataset with the missing dates (adding NA in other columns) ?

I tried this method to find the missing dates

```html
pd.date_range(df.Date_.min(), df.Date_.max()).difference(df.Date_)
```

but this doen't work well with the hours as it returned only 1 missing hour this day at 6am.

[image]

Comment: Doing some research, by chance I found something to resample with .asfreq..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using resample it works

apply(lambda x : x.set_index('Date_').resample('H')